# Retrieving image files from parse - android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve images that I have upload from my app:

```
intent = getIntent();
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Items");
    query.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                setTitle(object.getString("name"));
                textPlatform.setText(object.getString("platform"));
                textPrice.setText(String.valueOf(object.getDouble("price")));
                textDelivery.setText(String.valueOf(object.getDouble("delivery")));
                textLocation.setText(object.getString("location"));
                textCondition.setText(object.getString("condition"));
                textSeller.setText(object.getString("seller"));
                ParseFile applicantResume = (ParseFile) object.get("image");
                applicantResume.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback()
                {
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)
                    {
                        if (e == null)
                        {
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                            imgItem.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

I can successfully retrieve the other items just not the file (which I know exists and is under the column "image").

Thank You in advanced

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: It shows a blank imageview and when I debug data is empty.

Comment: And what is e ? Which statement is executed? Is data.length 0? Or is data null?

Comment: e is null, data.length is 0 and data isn't null just empty

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.parse.com/questions/parsefile-pf-parsefile-objectgetlogo-returns-string-instead-of-file A little bit of googling reveiled many who have the same problem...

Comment: Thanks but they didn't solve the problem, I changed object.get to object.getParseFile

Answer (score 12):

This is how i am doing it:
I get the file from parse using getParseFile method:

```
ParseFile postImage = object.getParseFile(ParseConstants.PARSE_KEY_FILE);
String imageUrl = postImage.getUrl() ;//live url 
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
```

and then I use Picasso to display the image:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUri.toString()).into(mPostImage);
```

Comment: I like how you did this as I'm trying to use Picasso or Glide for images. What is the ParseContants.PARSE_KEY_FILE? The master key? Thanks :)

Comment: @SmiffyKmc ParseFile postImage =(ParseFile) user.get("Image"); this is an example

Comment: @ste9206 thanks for getting onto me. Managed to get it to work alright! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
by this you can display the image....   

 ParseFile image = (ParseFile) userData.getParseFile("user_image");

//call the function 

displayImage(image, image_expert);
```

//and here is the function

```
    private void displayImage(ParseFile thumbnail, final ImageView img) {

        if (thumbnail != null) {
            thumbnail.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                    if (e == null) {
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                data.length);

                        if (bmp != null) {

                            Log.e("parse file ok", " null");
                            // img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                            // (display.getWidth() / 5),
                            // (display.getWidth() /50), false));
                            img.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp, 10));
                            // img.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);



                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("paser after downloade", " null");
                    }

                }
            });
        } else {

            Log.e("parse file", " null");

            // img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            img.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }

    }
```